# How to add an and clause when using inSetBind

Tags: scala, slick

Trying to add a '&&' clause to my filter when using inSetBind but I can't.

This works:

```
db.run(lists.filter(f => f.id inSetBind(listIds)).result)
```

When I try to add a && clause I get an error:

db.run(lists.filter(f => f.id inSetBind(listIds) && (f.locationId === locationId)).result)

Error is:

```
ambiguous implicit values:
[error]  both value BooleanOptionColumnCanBeQueryCondition in object CanBeQueryCondition of type => slick.lifted.CanBeQueryCondition[slick.lifted.Rep[Option[Boolean]]]
[error]  and value BooleanCanBeQueryCondition in object CanBeQueryCondition of type => slick.lifted.CanBeQueryCondition[Boolean]
[error]  match expected type slick.lifted.CanBeQueryCondition[Nothing]
```

Comment: As a work around you could try doing two separate filters: `lists.filter(f => ...).filter(f => ...)`

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, it's a simple parse error. Scala sees

```
lists.filter(f => f.id inSetBind(listIds) && (f.locationId === locationId))
```

and parses it as

```
lists.filter(f => f.id (inSetBind(listIds) && (f.locationId === locationId)))
```

so it's understandably confused. Try

```
lists.filter(f => (f.id inSetBind(listIds)) && (f.locationId === locationId))
```

Or, probably more clear in this case

```
lists.filter(f => f.id.inSetBind(listIds) && (f.locationId === locationId))
```

Scala's precedence rules can be found [here](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#infix-operations). Infix operators that begin with a letter (such as `inSetBind`) have lower precedence than any other (infix) operator, which is why `&&` binds more tightly than it.